# Spellllang dependent key mapping

Tags: key-bindings, spell-checking

Is it possible to define mappings that only get active when a certain `spelllang` is set?

E.g. I want to set the following mapping, but only if I use `spelllang=de`.

```
inoremap oe ö
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conditionnal mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> oe ( &spelllang == "de" ) ? "ö" : "oe"
```

With `<expr>` specified Vim knows that when it sees `oe` as an input it should execute the rest of the mapping as a vimscript expression and map `oe` to the result of this expression.

Here the expression is a conditionnal operator: if `&spelllang == "de"` is true then return `ö` otherwise return `oe`.

See [`:h :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap-%3cexpr%3e)